# Problem with imakeidx in the index

Tags: indexing, imakeidx

I'm trying to align an item of my index. Concretely, the item is created by using imakeidx. My most relevant code is the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[nottoc,notindex]{tocbibind}% must go before imakeidx
\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[title=\'Indice de t\'erminos,intoc]
\geometry{a4paper,total={170mm,257mm},left=20mm,top=20mm}
      
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\pagestyle{headings}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}
\fancypagestyle{alfabetico}{
  \fancyhead{}
%  \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}
  \fancyhead[RE,LO]{Index}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\'Indice}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Cap\'itulo}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Anexo}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Bibliograf\'ia}
\renewcommand{\indexname}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Figura}
\renewcommand{\listfigurename}{\'Indice de figuras}
\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{\'Indice de tablas}

\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}[section]
\newtheorem{corolario}[teorema]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{lema}[teorema]{Lema}
\newtheorem{lem}[teorema]{Lema}
\newtheorem{prop}[teorema]{Proposici\'on}
\newtheorem{ex}[teorema]{Ejemplo}
\newtheorem{cor}[teorema]{Corolario}
\newtheorem{thm}[teorema]{Teorema}
\newtheorem{rem}[teorema]{Nota}
  
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{titlepage}
    
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

\include{Libro_intro}

\pagestyle{headings} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\newpage

\chapter{...}


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               ANEXO

\newpage
\thispagestyle{empty}

{\small
\include{Libro_anexo}
\cleardoublepage}

\pagestyle{headings} \pagestyle{fancy} \fancyhf{} \fancyhead[LO]{\leftmark} \fancyhead[RE]{\rightmark} \fancyhead[RO,LE]{\thepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               BIBLIOGRAFIA

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\include{Libro_bibliografia}
\cleardoublepage}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               ÍNDICE DE TÉRMINOS

\clearpage
\pagestyle{empty}
%\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\'Indice de t\'erminos}
\printindex % Que ponga el índice aquí
%\printindex[people]  %Añade índice de palabras


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%               NOTACIÓN

\newpage
\pagestyle{empty}
{\small
\include{Libro_simbolos}
\cleardoublepage}

\end{document}
```

I obtain this:

[image]

As we can see, appears a duplicated item and the items Bibliografía and Notación are following a bad alignement. Please, tell me how I can fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please make sure that your example is self contained. You are using files in the example that we do not have access to, thus we cannot test your code.

Comment: For example what is that `\tikzset` command doing there when you are not loading `tikz`. Please don't just ignore compilation errors

Comment: Sorry daleif, I did not know that you can compile my text. I only tried to post the more relevant code. Now is deleted the tikz package. For the index is not important.

Comment: As long as you do not provide something we can copy and test as is and the the same result as your issue, then we cannot help you. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, give some minutes to modify it, please (not close the post). But this code is calling to another .tex files, so you'll never could compile it.

Comment: Solved! Thanks daleif. Simplyfing the text I saw in the another .tex code to omitte. Also there was some white spaces type \text{{} Anexo} that change the alingment.